# Accessing CDK generated ARNs from SAM launch.json debug config

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-sam

I'm using the CDK to generate Node Lambdas.
I need to pass in the ARN of a created topic to the lambda. This is easy enough using environment variables and accessing topicArn from the CDK library.

I'm also using SAM to debug locally. To do this, I'm populating enviornment variables in launch.json.

The issue is that I don't know at write time the ARN of the topic. I guess that I could enter it manually, but that wouldn't scale and would be fragile when I tear down and rebuild the stack. Another idea might be to use the topic name, then at runtime do an SNS query to find that topic and pull its ARN. That seems messy too though.

Are there any tricks for referencing a CDK generated ARN in launch.json?

**cdk definition code**

```
// SNS
    const {SNSTopic} =  new CreateSNSTopicConstruct(this)
    

// Lambda
const handler = new aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(
    this,
    "MyLamda",
    {
        entry: "resources/source.ts",
        handler: "handler",
        environment:{
            SNS_TOPIC_ARN : SNSTopic.topicArn // This works fine for deployed code.

     }...
```

**launch.json**

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "aws": {
            "credentials": "profile:personal",
            "region": "ap-southeast-2"
        },
        "name": "_:resources/geotabFeedAccess.handler (nodejs14.x)",
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "code",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
            "lambdaHandler": "resources/source.handler"
        },
        "lambda": {
            "runtime": "nodejs14.x",
         
            "environmentVariables": {
                "SNS_TOPIC_ARN":"", // .... but how do I reference it here?

            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Does your question relate to \*VSCode\*?  Consider editing the question and tags accordingly.

Comment: hmm... yes, perhaps it does. Let me ponder that.